# Changing or disabling stemming used for certain language in SQL server 2012

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, sql-server-2012, full-text-indexing, stemming

We are supposed to use Danish as language when doing full text index search in SQL server 2012.

However, we have found some rather weird results (either undesirable or plain wrong or faulty) being returned when setting the language to Danish.

We believe it may be caused by the Stemming class used in Danish.

Is is possible to change or disable the Stemming class being used for a given language in SQL server 2012?

Examples of queries and results being returned with missing records would be:

Source record A: "Bekendtgørelse om undervisningsplan for køreuddannelsen".

Source record B: "forenede Nationers organisation for undervisningsmæssige, videnskabelige og kulturelle spørgsmål".

Query: Contains(Table.TheIndexedColumn, '"undervisnings*"')

Only returns record B, when it should return both records.